# Select statement to return constant when no records found in table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am have a table with data and now i need to return zero in select statement if there is no records in table for example. I need to use it in Stored Procedure.

```
-- If no records exists in below select statement
SELECT ID,Text,Date FROM tblData WHERE ID = 12

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT -5 AS ID
END
```

**Output:**

```
ID  Text  Date


ID
-5
```

**Expected output**

```
ID
-5
```

Comment: I suggest you use an output parameter or the stored procedure return code for this purpose.  Return an empty result set when no rows are found along with the rowcount separately.  Overloading the proc interface (different number of columns and using the ID column for a row count) is not a good coding practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Ta.ID IS NULL THEN TBL.ID 
ELSE Ta.ID END) AS ID,Ta.Text,Ta.Date
FROM (VALUES(-5)) AS TBL(ID)
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT ID,Text,Date FROM tblData WHERE ID = 12
)
AS Ta ON Ta.ID = Ta.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return 1 row even when there is no match, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN -5 ELSE MAX(ID) END) as ID
FROM tblData
WHERE ID = 12;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff. Please check my query and will you please update your query.

Comment: But if the WHERE clause doesn't return anything (i.e. ID = 12 does not exist) then the resultset will be empty.

Comment: @RhysJones . . . No.  An aggregation query without a `group by` always returns one row, even when there are no matches.  I use this construct fairly often when I need to be sure that one row is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I always use an Exists statment.

```
if exists(SELECT ID FROM tblData WHERE ID = 12)
    select 0 as RowsExist
else
    select 1 as RowsExist
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single scalar value you could use something like;

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ID FROM tblData WHERE ID = 12), 0) as ID
```

Rhys