# Mysql how to return NULL values if there is no record

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm working with a simple stored procedure to collect data from 2 tables and send back to PHP :

```
BEGIN

DECLARE cur_name VARCHAR(50);

SELECT currency_name INTO cur_name FROM currencies WHERE id = currency_id_var;
SELECT cur_name, sum(amount) AS income_amount, currency_id, month(income_date) AS month_of_income 
    FROM incomes 
    WHERE user_id = user_id_var 
        AND currency_id = currency_id_var 
        AND income_date > year_beginning_var 
        AND month(income_date) = month_var 
    GROUP BY currency_id;

END
```

It's working good, except when it is no record found in the 'incomes' table. I need a response from the procedure with the 'cur_name' set (it ALWAYS has some value) and the rest variables (income_amount, currency_id, month_of_income) set to NULL. 
Am I asking something that can not be done?
I was trying to make it work with *SELECT IFNULL* and *UNION SELECT NULL* kind of commands, no success...
Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089275/select-statement-to-return-constant-when-no-records-found-in-table-in-sql-server#answer-28090639)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine both queries into a `LEFT JOIN`, like so:

```
SELECT currency_name as cur_name, 
       income_amount,
       currency_id,
       month_of_income
    FROM currencies
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT cur_name, sum(amount) AS income_amount, currency_id, month(income_date) AS month_of_income 
                FROM incomes 
                WHERE user_id = user_id_var 
                    AND currency_id = currency_id_var 
                    AND income_date > year_beginning_var 
                    AND month(income_date) = month_var 
                GROUP BY currency_id;
        )
        ON currency_id = currencies.id
    WHERE currencies.id = currency_id_var;
```

Untested, but you get the idea: it's a `LEFT JOIN`, so it is guaranteed to return at least one row for each matching row in the left table (`currencies`), and if the right table (the subquery) doesn't yield any results, the corresponding fields are returned as `NULL`.

For better readability, I would consider moving the subquery to a view, and left-join on that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I got the point, but I'm not a SQL expert and it seems there's a syntax error (SQL Error 1064) in your code snippet...

Comment: Sub Queries must have alias - in this case between ) and on I suggest ) s on